# Trim whitespaces from specific tags from XML

Tags: xslt

Given I have the following XML:

```
   <listitem>
    <para>
      <emphasis role="bold">S</emphasis>
      top
    </para>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
    <para>
      <emphasis role="bold">O</emphasis>
      bserve
    </para>
   </listitem>
   <para>To learn more about this training, visit
    <link xlink:href="https://www.some.link">some link</link>
    .
   </para>
```

I want to trim whitespaces from the para with the emphasis tags, and make them one line in my html, but without affecting the link. I've tried using normalize-space, but this will trim all white spaces, including from the paragraph with the link. Also tried unsuccessfully with xsl:strip-space. Any ideas what else I could try?

this is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="db xs">

    <xsl:output
          method="html"
          indent="yes"
          encoding="utf-8"
      />
    
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:template>
    
    
      <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </p>
      </xsl:template>
      
        <xsl:template match="db:emphasis[@role='italic']">
        <i>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:emphasis[@role='bold']">
        <strong>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </strong>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="db:listitem">
    <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
  </xsl:template>
    

  <xsl:template match="db:link">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="self::node()/@xlink:href"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="self::node()"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My HTML result:

```
<li xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <strong>S</strong>
    top
</li>
<li xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <strong>O</strong>
    bserve
</li>
To learn more about this training, visit
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
href="https://www.some.link">some link</a>
.
```

My expected result:

```
<li xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <strong>S</strong>top
</li>
<li xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <strong>O</strong>bserve
</li>
To learn more about this training, visit
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
href="https://www.some.link">some link</a>
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<xsl:template match="db:para[db:emphasis]//text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It did the job. Just to be more specific to this case I've added `db:listitem/db:para[db:emphasis]//text()` to the match attribute. Thanks